# How to insert, update, delete content/data into file using google app engine php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, insert, filestream

I want to insert, update and delete content using php.

## I follow example like here, (Ref: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/)

Streamed file write
Alternatively, you could use fopen/fwrite to write data in a streaming fashion:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('gs://my_bucket/some_file.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'Hello');
fclose($fp); ?>
```

## My File Code:

```
<?php
$jsonClass=null;
    if(file_exists("classes.json"))
    {
        $string1 = file_get_contents("classes.json");
        $jsonClass = json_decode ($string1,true);
    }
    if($jsonClass != null )
    {
        echo "Before adding new class information <br>";
        foreach ($jsonClass as $rsClass)
        {
            echo stripslashes($rsClass['classname']);  
        }
    }       
    $fp=fopen('gs://r-restful-ws.appspot.com/classes.json','w');
    fwrite($fp, 'Hello');
    fclose($fp);

    if(file_exists("classes.json"))
    {
        $string1 = file_get_contents("classes.json");
        echo $string1;
    } ?>
```

===========================================================

But still I am not able to insert content into my file.

please help me out on this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: Rushi, it works for me with my bucket. Try the code in the link and, if you it fails, let me know the output of the logs in the Developers' Console. The only thing it could go wrong is that you didn't upload the original classes.json file. http://pastebin.com/d4a4EZDx

Comment: You should use the full path, i.e. gs://r-restful-ws.appspot.com/classes.json, when calling file_exists & file_get_contents